# How to assign a string id to UI elements.

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm developing an app on android and I am generating UI elements in a loop. But I need these elements to have an id with letters and numbers, for example `"rl1"` or `"rl2"`. I was trying to use the method `RelativeLayout.setId()` but, that method only accepts `int`. Is there a way I can set an ID as I want without being limited to numbers?

Thanks.

Here is the code I am trying to make work.

```
for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
{
    //gets the frameview where the elements will be created.
    String LinearLayoutId = "frameview1";
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(LinearLayoutId, "id", "com.myapp.ERS");
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(resID);

    //creates the RelativeLayout that will hold the ImageIcon and the TextView
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,40 );
    rl.setLayoutParams(lp);
    rl.setId("rl"); /// >>>> I would like here to set and ID of "rl1" for example.
    rl.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bk36));

    //creates the image icon within the layout at the left side
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            40,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );

    image.setLayoutParams(lp);
    String imageicon = "icon_"+i;
    resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageicon, "drawable", "com.myapp.ERS");
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resID));  //sets the icon
    rl.addView(image); //adds the ImageView to the relative layout


    //creates the TextView within the layout with a 40 margin to the left
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
    lp.setMargins(40, 0, 0, 0);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    String textViewID = "tv"+i;
    resID = getResources().getIdentifier(textViewID, "string", "com.myapp.ERS");
    tv.setText(getResources().getString(resID));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setTextSize(25);
    rl.addView(tv);//adds the TextView to the relative layout
    rl.setOnClickListener(mAddListener);
    linearLayout.addView(rl);//adds the RelativeLayout to the LinearLayout
}
```

and then I have the OnCLickListener like this...

```
private OnClickListener mAddListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent;
        Bundle bundle;

        String id = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
        id = id.replaceAll("\\D+","");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(id);

        intent = new Intent(ERS.this, ShowInfo.class);
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("key", value);  
        System.out.println(v.getId());
        intent.putExtras(bundle); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

I have tried to set up numeric IDs, but then when I Look for them with:

```
String id = getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
```

It can't find them.

I had all of this in an `xml` file to begin with, but it was really long because there are about forty items in the list, and it was complicated for me to go and change a letter for example in all of them.  I came up with this idea to generate them at runtime in a `for loop`. I am testing in the meantime with ten, but I can't get it to work.

If I am doing something incorrect, then pardon me, but I am new to this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why dont you try using SharedPreferences as an alternative in case you want to access the elements which you give some ID elsewhere in some other activity.

Comment: I am new to this, and I don't know what you mean by SharedPreferences

Comment: Check this link on how to use it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: @jerisalan if you look through the code the elements being generate are layouts, ImageViews and other UI elements.  I don't think SharedPreferences are really the way to go to store IDs for these.

Answer (score 0):

You may still find it easier to go back to `XML` layouts and use the `R class` to generate meaningful IDs. Although as you haven't included the original `xml` file you refer to at the end of the question, so I can only guess at the problem you had with it. It does seem to fit the bill though, and would allow you to create something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/hellotextview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="Hi there"/>
```

The `android:id="@+id/hellotextview"` generates an id that can be used elsewhere in your project.  In your java code you could access that specific `TextView`  with something similar to:

```
TextView helloText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hellotextview);
```

The `R.id.hellotextview` is a int automatically generated when the project is built (in `gen/R.java`), but as you get to pick the name you can assign them something relevant to you and your project.  So instead of trying to use strings values such as `"rl1"` and `"rl2"` that you mentioned, you could use `R.id.rl1` and `R.id.rl2`.

As well as individual UI elements, you can also use the same technique for strings (in `res/values/strings.xml`), and other resources stored under the project's `res/` folder, such as icons, media files, etc.  In the case of strings you would access them `getString(R.string.some_name_given_by_you);`

See [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) at the Android Developers site for more info.

Comment: The things is that when I set the onclicklistener, within the method, I obtain the ID of the textview that was clicked, and then I call an activity with a web view, and depending on the ID of the textview that was clicked, It will load a certain local html file that is related only to that specific textview. So, that is why I was trying to setID whenever I generated the textview at runtime. What I ended up going is just setting the Id to 1, 2, 3, 4, and then just sending that ID to the web view. I don't if it makes sense but it worked that way.